# How to add a List to an RDD in Spark using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am pretty new to the world of Spark. I am starting with an RDD, then I am doing a `.map()` to get certain values from the RDD, which in turn returns a List type. The values in the list are good, but my assignemnt requires me to return an RDD. How do I do that?

P.S. due to the fact that this is an university assignement, I cannot disclose the actual code because it's against university policies. However, feel free to ask anything that's not clear with my question because I know stackoverflow is very specific about that type of stuff.

Comment: `map` function doesn't return a List... `collect` or `take` does. If you cannot show your exact code, then show a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this is an assignment where you're not allowed to get help with your code, you're probably expected to know how to do this already. [Here's](https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-spark-rdd/different-ways-to-create-spark-rdd/#from-parallelize) an article talking about how to turn a list to an RDD.